# Error while installing agora in Angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqnve.jpg),
I don't know this is Angular/npm/agora error but when I try to install angular material or bootstrap, everything works fine but whenever I try to install agora, it throws error.

Answer (score 1):

From the error you can see you have Angular 11.2.7 installed but ngx-agora is only compatible with versions >= 8.0.0 and < 9.0.0.